# button to download an attachment in the email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I add a pdf as an attachment to my email, what I want to do is create a button in the body of my email to download this attachment, is that possible? How could I solve it?

MAILER:

```
attachments.inline["file.pdf"] = file.pdf
```

HTML:

```
<a href="<%= attachments['file.pdf'].url %>" class="btn-download-pdf" download>Download PDF</a>
```

This doesn't work for me, is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: so did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

To enable that functionality attach a link to the pdf file as follows
`<a href="[SITE_URL]/file.pdf" class="btn-download-pdf" download>Download PDF</a>`